# s3cmd Error while downloading the file onto linux ubuntu server

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-s3, download

I have successfully setup using the s3cmd on my CentOS server.

But getting one issue in trying to Download the S3 Files onto my own server.

I have tried all other operations like uploading files to s3 using s3cmd, creating folder etc. and everything is working fine. But only the download of file is not happening.

Here is the code on console I am using

```
[root@myserver tmp]# s3cmd get s3://a_s3_bucket/test.csv
download: 's3://a_s3_bucket/test.csv' -> './test.csv'  [1 of 1]
download: 's3://a_s3_bucket/test.csv' -> './test.csv'  [1 of 1]
ERROR: S3 error: 400 (Bad Request)
[root@myserver tmp]#
```

However the uploading is working fine:

```
s3cmd put FILE /var/www/html/myserver/test.csv s3://a_s3_bucket
```

I have also identified that the following code works

```
s3cmd get s3://a_s3_bucket/*.csv
```

but individual file download code doesn't work.

Can anyone help with downloading of file please.

Comment: Try the download command with the `-v` (verbose) and/or `-d` (debug) flags to look for any useful information.

Comment: I had the same problem. Solved it by setting the `bucket_location` in .s3cfg ... seems like `put` determines it automatically, while `get` needs it to be set.